# Find $D_1 f(u,v,w), D_2 f(u,v,w), D_3 f(u,v,w)$

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

$h:R^3 \rightarrow R$ is continuously differentiable and $f:R^3 \rightarrow R$ is defined by 
$f(u,v,w) = (3u+2v)h(u^2,v^2,uvw)$

Find $D_1 f(u,v,w), D_2 f(u,v,w), D_3 f(u,v,w)$.

So far I have

$D_1 f(u,v,w) = 3(h(u^2,v^2,uvw)) + (3u+2v)(D_1 h(u^2,v^2,uvw)(2u) + D_3h(u^2,v^2,uvw)(vw)) $

$D_2 f(u,v,w) = 2(h(u^2,v^2,uvw)) + (3u+2v)(D_2 h(u^2,v^2,uvw)(2v) + D_3h(u^2,v^2,uvw)(uw)) $

$D_3 f(u,v,w) = (3u+2v)(D_3h(u^2,v^2,uvw)(uv)) $

Is this correct or did I deal with (3u+2v) completely wrong?

Comment: It seems all right to me.

Comment: In the second one, replace the $3$ by a $2$ since the derivative of $2v$ is $2$. Everything else looks good.

Comment: Woops, that was a copy and paste error. Have 2 on my worksheet. Thanks for that.